# Find $E(Y_{(n)})$ when n = 2..

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n$ be independent random variables, each with a beta distribution, with α = β = 2.

Find the density function of $Y_{(n)}$.

$f_{Y_{(n)}} (y) = n(6y-6y^2)[3y-2y^3]^{n-1}$, for $0<y<1$. Is this right?

Also, find $E(Y_{(n)})$ when n = 2.

I am a little confused for the setup for $E(Y_{(2)})$ ... my attempt is $\int_0^1 2u(6u-6u^2)[3u-2u^3] du$? Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing $Y_{(n)}$ is the $n$-th order statistic.

In general, the joint distribution of the order statistics of i.i.d. random variables with density $f$$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ as $Y_1 \geq Y_2 \geq \ldots \geq Y_n$ are given by $f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=n!f(y_1)f(y_2)\ldots f(y_n)$ on $y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \ldots \geq y_n$ and $0$ otherwise.

The largest order statistic has cdf $F_1(y) = F(y)^n$, and the second largest has $F_2(y) = F(y)^n+n F(y)^{n-1}(1-F(y))$. The first term accounts for the event that all the $X_k$'s are $\leq y$ and the second term accounts for $n-1$ of the $X_k$'s are less than or equal to $y$ and one is greater than $y$ (there are $n$ such ways this can occur).

You can find more information on order statistics in many books - I took this from Vijay Krishna's Auction Theory, but most introductory mathematical statistics books (such as Hogg, Mckean, Craig's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics) at least have a section on this.

Comment: do i need to put into n = 2 into the density?

Comment: $E(Y_{(2)})$ should be .6286? right